# How can I find a value and substitute the value in XSL / XML?

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have the doc .XML:

```
...
...
< memberValuePairs >
    < member path="Blabla">bla bla< /member >
    < member path="Zzzz">zz z z zzz< /member >
    < member path="word">my text< /member >
< /memberValuePairs >
...
...
```

I need to replace the value of the tag, "word", in this case, the words: "my text" to "my another text".
I have the file XML from command: `< xsl:copy >` but I don't know how to find and replace the value of a tag.

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="member[@path='word']/text()[1]">
  <xsl:text>my another text</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on (what I *assume* is the source XML document)**:

```
<memberValuePairs>
    <member path="Blabla">bla bla</member>
    <member path="Zzzz">zz z z zzz</member>
    <member path="word">my text</member>
</memberValuePairs>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<memberValuePairs>
   <member path="Blabla">bla bla</member>
   <member path="Zzzz">zz z z zzz</member>
   <member path="word">my another text</member>
</memberValuePairs>
```